# Split string by any punctuation and whitespace in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, regex, string, tensorflow2.0

I want to split strings in a tensor into parts separated by punctuation or whitespace (sometimes there are multiple consecutive whitespace characters). I've tried `t = tf.strings.split(t, sep = "\W-_.,")` but it doesn't work the way I want. How to do it properly?

Comment: You did not use the square brackets, `sep = "[\W-_.,]"`, but in fact, it is just the same as `sep = r"[\W_]"` (`\W` does not match only `_`)

Comment: Define "punctuation".